# Visual Studio 2005 on Windows 7 always requests adminstrator permissions

Tags: visual-studio-2005, windows-7-x64

I am running Visual Studio 2005 with the Vista-compatible SP1 installed on Windows 7 64 bit. I get this error (see screenshot) every time I start Visual Studio, even when I use the "Run as Administrator" menu option and/or set the shortcut options to always run as administrator. How do I fix this?
[image: Error Dialog "Adminstrator permissions are recommended for running Visual Studio 2005 SP1"]

Answer (score 0):

**Run as administrator** is fine but, have you tried un-checking the **"Always show this message"** option? I guess you haven't try that

Comment: How do you know the warning is safe to ignore?

Comment: If you're running it in administrator mode then it's way sure its safe.  And by the way the above message is **Information** and not a **Warning** so you can un-check and continue @smh